# pass model into login action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, model, authorization

My Start view is posting form data into parameter of action in Users controller.

```
public ActionResult GetUsers(RouteData routeData)
 {
  ...
 }
```

All worked well until I put authorization attribute on this method and added into Web.config file like bellow,

```
<authentication mode="Forms"><forms loginUrl="~/LogIn/LogIn" />
</authentication>
```

I have expected form data to be automatically redirected into **LogIn** action, but it is empty.

```
public ActionResult LogIn(RouteData routeData){ }
```

My question is, how can I pass this model through LogIn action, into LogIn view.

Comment: What is "form data to be automatically redirected into LogIn action" ?? What is form data ? and which form ??

Comment: ... its actually very simple situation, my strongly typed Start view used to open GetUsers action where it passed model fields into action parameter. After introducing the authentication functionality my Start view is calling LogIn action instead but for some reason doesn't populate model fields in LogIn action parameter ...

Comment: Please post your code, so we can help, your controller, view, viewmodel if you have one